# Как реализовать поиск в select по option без bootstrap

Tags: html

Как реализовать поиск в `select` по `option` без `bootstrap select`?

Comment: Написать свой, на чистом js. Образец можете найти в bootstrap select, так что получится примерно тоже самое.

Comment: А причом тут PHP ? Задавайте подробные вопросы,ато никто не обязан догадываться и если не хотите получить аналогичный ответ "как хочешь".

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) или [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

Включите следующие строки кода в разделе  вашего HTML.

> <Link
>   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css"
>   rel="stylesheet" />  
> <script
>   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Инициализируйте Select2 для элемента , который вы хотите сделать удивительным.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>
```

```js
$(".js-states").select2();
```

```css
.js-states {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-states form-control">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм, вспомнил чистый хтмл поиск, возможно не к месту (не select), но все же...

**P.S. список не выпадает на мозилле, но появится при двойном клике)**

```html
<h1>Plain html search</h1>

<input list="test" placeholder="Type from the list...">

<datalist id="test">
  <option value="one"></option>
  <option value="two"></option>
  <option value="three"></option>
  <option value="four"></option>
  <option value="five"></option>
  <option value="six"></option>
  <option value="seven"></option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -1):

ни фига не понятно, но если вы хотите в элементе select узнать выбранную опцию, то:
`/* получаем содержимое выбранной опции
* id - это id select-а
*/
function getSelectedOption (id) {

    var select = document.querySelector('#select'); // любым способом получить ссылку на select, в данном случае забираем по id
    var options = select.children; // сохраняем ссылки на опции
    var len = select.children.length; // получаем количество опций в select
    // перебираем опции
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // если опция выбрана (selected), то возвращаем её содержимое
        if (option[i].selected == true) {
            return option[i].value;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Если "ни фига не понятно", зачем отвечать? ["Уберегите себя от разочарования и не отвечайте на вопросы, которые непонятны или не содержат конкретных подробностей, что не позволяет однозначно определить проблему"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)